# Is CSS display:table with 100% height content buggy in IE9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a relatively straightforward JSFiddle that seems to do something (what I want) in IE11 and Chrome, but something else (exceeds the window height and shows a scroll bar) in IE9. Is this an IE9 bug; am I misusing the display style in some way I could easily fix to make IE9 treat it the same way IE11 does?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bluemonkmn/6J5ct/

HTML

```
<div class="fixedRow">
    <div class="td">Header</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="td">
        <div class="thing">All Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fixedRow">
    <div class="td">Footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}

body {
    display: table;
}

.fixedRow {
    display:table-row;
    background-color:pink;    
}

.content {
    display:table-row;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: cyan;
}

.td {
    display:table-cell;
}

.content .td {
    height: 100%;
}

.thing {
    display: block;
    background-color: papayawhip;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with your `.thing`, which tries to be 100% of the height of the page, rather than the height of its parent. The simple solution is to remove the `height` from it and make the parent td `papayawhip`. http://jsfiddle.net/6J5ct/6/ Would that work? Otherwise I may have to experiment some more, but then you'll have to show the complete HTML.

Comment: @MrLister The complete HTML is available by viewing source of the JSFiddle code, but there's really nothing of consequence outside what you see -- just body and html tags enclosing what you see. The reason I have the DIVs nested this way is to convey the fact that I can't flatten the structure because the innermost DIV is a control based on SlickGrid, so I don't have a lot of control over what's going on in there. I can specify the height of it, but I don't think I can flatten the hierarchy to get any better results.

Comment: OK, but does my solution work for you? Can you remove the height altogether and give its parent div the same background color?

Comment: @MrLister The question/problem isn't about applying a background color, but rather about sizing nested DIVs. The background colors I'm using are only to make visible which DIVs are consuming space. What I really would like is to know if nested DIVs can size themselves appropriately in this context. In that sense this solution doesn't help me. However my real-world problem was solved by moving my footer above some script tags and eliminating one level of nesting, so in a sense flattening the hierarchy does solve my problem. But the question, now acedemic, was supposed to be about nested DIVs.

Comment: It's not nested divs. The innermost element is a div, yes, but its parent is a table cell! Table cells act differently from block elements, no matter if you design them as `<td>` or as `<div style="display:table-cell">`. If they were all normal divs with no `display` property, they would all act the same and you wouldn't have differences with `100%` in one and `100%` in the other.

Comment: @MrLister Well, the fact remains that it displays "properly" (the way I want and expect) in IE11 and Chrome, so I'm guessing they found something wrong with what IE9 was doing and fixed it. I'm just not clear exactly what. I'm guessing your comment about the 100% being interpreted as 100% of the page instead of the container is it. When nested inside an element that's displaying as a table cell,  the height was maybe being miscalculated in IE9. That's all I'm trying to confirm. Is that a bug, and are there easy/good work-arounds for it?